# using and consuming typescript npm modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

So I want to write shared code in typescript, make an npm package of it and be able to install it..

So I tried writing an external lib like this :

```
export class Lib {
   constructor(){

   }

   getData(){
      console.log('getting data from lib');
   }
```

}

Running npm link on external lib

And running npm link "package" in consuming apps directory, to have it appear in it's node_modules

```
consuming-app
   index.ts
   node_modules/ 
       external-package-with-typescript
```

index.ts is simple it just looks like :

```
import { Lib } from 'external-package-with-typescript'

var l = new Lib();
```

Then I try to bundle it all with

```
browser index.ts -p tsify --global --debug > bundle.js
```

This results in an error from the external package

```
'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I can get it to work with https://github.com/basarat/ts-npm-module-consume
But that produces an output that looks like

```
consuming-app/ index.ts
external-package-with-typescript/ index.ts
```

Which is of no value to me as I want one .js file that I can include in index.html

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `declare` instead of export?

Comment: wouldnt that make it more of definition file?

Comment: I guess have a look at the options being passed through, are you targeting ES5 or ES6?

Comment: I am targeting es5